# Babylonjs/React Append OBJ files

Tags: reactjs, append, babylonjs

Trying to append an OBJ file to the scene but it is not loading. There are no errors in the console but when logging the scene I am not seeing the mesh being fetched.

```
// This code block is not working as it should

BABYLON.SceneLoader.Append("mesh/", "HEAD.obj", scene, () => {
      scene.createDefaultCameraOrLight(true, true, true);
      scene.createDefaultEnvironment();
    });
```

The files are setup up as such

mesh/HEAD.obj
scenes/Scene.js (This is where I am trying to load the mesh)

*This wouldn't matter because as mesh/ it would search localhost:3000/mesh/HEAD.obj which is it's proper location.*

Additionally, I have installed and imported babylonjs-loaders in the component as well but this is still not working. Again, no errors in the logs :(

Comment: Do you see the file downloaded (in the network tab of your inspector)? Is there an error there? maybe 404 or wrong mime type?

Comment: Disregard. I resolved this.